# Is it legal to define a function to be undefined for some x?

Tags: calculus, functions, definition

Is the following definition legal:

```
f(x) = 1 for 0<x<1, and undefined otherwise.
```

Such functions clearly exist, but the question is if it is legal to just state "undefined" as part of the definition, without supplying the cause.

If this is not legal - how come? otherwise is there an example for such a definition from a renowned textbook in calculus?

Edit / Clarification: Some functions that are defined from (0,1) to R can also be extended to be from [0,1] to R. I need to prove that there exists a function that is defined at (0,1) but has no 0/1 limits. There are plenty of examples but is just writing "udefined" for outside (0,1) enough? Would such a definition constitute a function?

Answer (score 4):

When one defines a function $f$, part of the definition of $f$ is its domain and codomain. We usually write $f:A \to B$ if the domain is $A$ and the codomain is $B$. When one says $f(x)=1$ for $0<x<1$ and undefined otherwise, one simply means $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$.

As a side note, things in math aren't "legal" or "illegal". They can be correct, incorrect, valid, invalid, etc. But legality is something entirely different...

Comment: Well, there are maths "laws", though no legal or illegal, or a police force to enforce the laws. Maybe rather than a legal system maths need masked vigilantes to patrol these dangerous streets with catchphrases like "You have been invalidated".

Comment: By "legal" - I mean does it constitute a function?

Comment: @user1581390 Yes, it constitutes a function whose domain is $(0,1)$.